# How do you branch and merge with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging

How do you [branch and merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html) with Apache Subversion using the TortoiseSVN client?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My easy click-by-click instructions (**specific to TortoiseSVN**) are in Stack Overflow question *[What is the simplest way to do branching and merging using TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461922)*.

Answer (score 15):

[Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

A very good resource for source control in general. Not really TortoiseSVN specific, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try *[Version Control for the Standalone Programmer - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/work/XTortoiseSVN.aspx)* or perhaps *[Merging with TortoiseSVN](http://www.kenegozi.com/Blog/2007/07/30/merging-with-tortoisesvn.aspx)*.