# Subversion and revision engineering - what are the best web resources to read about?

Tags: svn, revision

We are migrationg from CVS to SVN and embracing some kind of revision management in order to enforce order to development/testing/release cycle. We are currently testing, developing and releasing on the same code line, we know its a bad practice and we want to make end to it.

What are your experience, know how, suggestions working with source code tree.

We are building small/average (2-5 months) custom projects and we have to give early access to customer for review. Requirement creep is common.

EDIT:
please note, i need not only advice on subversion, but more on how whole devel/test/deploy cycle is reflected in trunk/branches/tags/versions etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion makes it easier to branch than CVS (in [GIT](http://git.or.cz/) branches are even cheaper).  I recommended that you make branches for major revisions, and have a planned merging of the branches back into the trunk.  *Be vary careful of going long periods of not merging back into the branch*, as you it will become more and more difficult the longer you wait.

There are also services out there that provide integrated bug tracking/deployment etc, if you need to get off the ground quickly, and don't want to manage all the server/setup stuff:

- http://beanstalkapp.com/
- http://unfuddle.com/
- http://www.assembla.com/

**Some resources:**

**This particular book answered a lot of the questions I had initially:**
http://www.pragprog.com/titles/svn/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion

**Searching Further on stackoverflow:**
[Good branching and merging tutorials for TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90/good-branchmerge-tutorials-for-tortoise-svn)

**Cal Henderson (developer at Flickr.com) Presentation** at FOWA in Miami that I attended:
http://cdn4.libsyn.com/carsonsystems/Cal_Henderson.mp3

**The Free "Bible" of Subversion (Chapter on Merging)**:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html

Answer (score 3):

- "Branch early, branch often."
- All builds should be completely reproducible without having to pour through logs (consider tagging every build)
- If you use an issue tracker then require all check-ins to have a (valid) issue ID included in the commit message (add a pre-hook to check this).
- Only the build team should be allowed to make production branches (developers should be encouraged to make personal branches for any non-trivial task)
- Build continuously and ensure that everyone is aware that breaking the build is a big deal.
- Read the whole SVN book, then read it again. You need to know this tool backwards and forwards. Hold training sessions for your developers ("how to create a temporary branch for my work", "how to merge", etc).

... There is an lack of good reading on this subject, but if I had to recommend one book to a shop completely green in SCM it would be "The Build Master" by Vincent Maraia. It's very short on details but easy to read and provides a (very very brief) overview of SCM good-ideas that make great sense once you know them but which for some reason so many shops completely lack.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A very good resource for source control :

- [Agile-Version-Control](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control)