# Repetitive merge changes on tortoise svn trunk to branch merge

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am getting repetitive merge changes on tortoise svn trunk to branch merge. 
What I was hoping was that once I do the merge it should not come agian. Here are the steps I believe I am doing. Need help if I am doing something wrong.

1. I am on the root of my branch folder. I am not using `svn switch` or anything, but definitely I am at the root of my branch folder. And changes on commit go into branch only. Hope that doesn't make any difference.
2. I do right-click. Go to Tortoise SVN -> Merge -> Merge a Range of revision -> Give my trunk URL in my merge from drop down -> Leave the range of revisions blank. -> Do a merge (have tried test merge and record merge all sorts of option, but I believe clicking on Merge button is the right approach, right?)
3. Then I do get changes. Here after some reading through stackoverflow questions I have tried SVN commit and even doing an `svn update` before `svn commit`. The change gets committed with incremented revision.
4. I check the svnmerge properties too. It shows correctly the right revision OR a one revision less just before commit.
5. **PROBLEM** is that when I do the merge again, I get the same set of changes. Isn't is that same set of changes should not come again? I expect it not to come up again if I repeat the step 2. Please help me with the right approach.

Comment: How do you know you are getting the same set of changes again?  If after Step 2, you do a Commit, does it say you have modifications to commit?  If you have already done step 2 and committed to the branch, then doing Step 2 again should not make any changes.

Comment: Yeah exactly.. but that's what it is showing. It is showing classes to bechecked in again.

Comment: Has svn:mergeinfo something to do with it?

Comment: What do you see when you do a "diff" on the files to be checked in again?