# Svn Branching and merging back to trunk

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good branching and merging tutorials for TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90/good-branching-and-merging-tutorials-for-tortoisesvn)

Here is my setup.
I have created a repo. I have trunk, branches and tags. All latest codes are in trunk. I tag each version that is released to production environment. Then I had problem when there were some urgent issue needed to fix in production environment. My trunk was not stable and those issue needed to be fixed. So after that I started branching releases then tag them and release to production. Now for any urgent issues, I could work on release branch and fix thing and send to production. (is this good use of branching?) Now after i make changes to release branch. How do i merge codes changed to trunk?
Any help would be appreciated. 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a good use of branching and merging.

Tag releases you make to production. Try to fix in the trunk if possible (keep your process Agile, if possible), but if (too) unstable, fix in the branch and deploy to production. Merge the fix up to the trunk.

Conversely, you may discover something bad when working on trunk. You may want to merge a fix to a branch and deploy that to production too.

For the *how*, see the documentation http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html or another question on this subject [Good branching and merging tutorials for TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90/good-branching-and-merging-tutorials-for-tortoisesvn) .

Comment: Giving reading links without a direct answer is not a good practice.

Comment: Well, since the quesion is a very genralsied one, I also recommend reading these links and come back here for any specific doubts (After the homework is complete) :)

Comment: Is my approach to branching right?